# GAN's for data augmentation

Tags: deep-learning, data-mining, cnn, gan, data-augmentation

I am working to augment my data using Generative Adversarial Networks, I have used Deep Convolutional GAN's for this purpose but they are not learning the right data distribution, so please suggest me which GAN's to use for this purpose ?

Comment: How do you know the true label of your generated data?

Comment: @kbrose true label of the generated data ? I did not get it. Actually we try to penalize generator loss by classifying its data as fake, at the end we get highly refined images

Comment: Yes, but you say that you are trying "to augment my data". I assumed by that you meant you wanted to augment the existing data you have for e.g. a classification or regression task, but perhaps I don't understand the situation correctly.

Comment: @kbrose Ok, I have 300 images of number plates, and I want to generate more number plates like this so I can have plenty of training Images for Number Plate detection, that is why I used GANs for doing this so, hope you understand the situation

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. You want to generate more images and then have a human label the generated number plates to use for training data?

Comment: @kbrose yes you are right

Answer (score 1):

So there are few possible answers to your question.
First of all you are mentioning Deep Convolutional GAN's which refers to Architecture of a Network. So you can either change Architectures or change Loss functions which are used in GANs which both can have an positive or negativ effect.
Also you mention not learning the right data distribution, it also cann occur that your data is the problem, i.e. too low number of samples, not representative samples etc.

There is no definite answer to your question, you have to try which works best for your dataset.

But a few hints for losses you can try: Wassersteindistance, Improved WassersteinGAN, Boundary Equilibrium GAN. In all of their publications also the architectures are published.